# Swift: How do I add a dictionary to an array?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift

I already read Apple's documentation, but it did not cover all my questions.

```
var datalist: [[String:String]]=[]
var detaildata: [String: String] = [:]

detaildata["orange"]="byebye"
detaildata["apple"]="hello"
detaildata["grape"]="goodbye"

datalist += detaildata  // error -> Playground execution failed: <EXPR>:28:1: error: '[[String : String]]' is not identical to 'UInt8'
//datalist += detaildata
//^
```

I just want add key/value data in array but it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `+=` operator, you have to supply an array and not an array item - just turn `detaildata` into an array:

```
datalist += [detaildata]
```